# jQuery taking too long to render animation over large list of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

On my current project I have a table containing rows of items.
Each item has a hidden checkbox over which an animation is executed as shown:

```
$('.elemToShow').each(function(){
    $(this).show('fast');
});
```

The problem is that as the list of items gets bigger, the function takes so much time to render that it simply "pops" on the screen after a while, instead of showing the animation as expected.

Is there any way to execute this function so that it animates regardless of the list size?

Comment: If you're applying `class="elemToShow"` to each list item, of course it will be slow. Consider just adding that class to the list container instead.

Comment: Is this an animation you could achieve with CSS by merely adding a class and letting CSS3 animations handle it (and letting old browsers degrade gracefully?)

Comment: @Kolink unfortunately I'm currently working with tables, and what I want to animate is just an element inside of each row ( a checkbox to be clear). I already edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be animating then...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may work.

Javascript:

```
function showCheckbox(element, elementClass, parentClass) {
    var $element = element;

    $element.show(200, function() {
        var $next = $(this).closest(parentClass).find(elementClass+':hidden').first();

        if ($next[0]) {
            showCheckbox($next, elementClass, parentClass);
        }
    })
}

showCheckbox($('.element:first'), '.element', 'tr');
```

Here is the HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="element" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="element" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="element" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="element" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="element" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="element" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="element" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="element" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.element {display:none}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No need for the overhead of the loop here, jQuery will already perform an `each` based on that selector. Try this:

```
$('.elemToShow').show('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the end of the world if older browsers don't support it, try this CSS:

```
.elemToShow {
    animation: fadein 0.5s ease;
}
@keyframes fadein {from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
```

Remove the jQuery fade-in. By having the browser handle fading, it should be a lot smoother.

(Note that Chrome still uses the `-webkit-animation` and `@-webkit-keyframes` prefixed versions, but that will change next version)

Comment: This is pretty interesting! How does this behave on IE?

Comment: IE10 supports it, older versions just show the box without fading.